# How to add a message that will be logged after every mocha command run?

Tags: mocha.js

I write mocha tests and I'd like to write a warning which should be displayed for every future test runner. Where should I include it?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I found the solution during writing the question. That was sufficient to add these two files:

**setup.js:**

```
console.log('my warning message: be alert!')
```

**test/mocha.opts:**

```
--file ./setup.js
```